# ¿Cómo ejecutar mi aplicación de android studio en mi teléfono mediante "instant run"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hardware

Buenas, estoy iniciando en Android Studio y quisiera que me ayudaran con un error que me aparece cuando quiero correr la aplicación en mi teléfono.

Cuando me voy a: Run -> Run 'app' y elijo que se ejecute en mi teléfono conectado a mi pc vía USB me da el siguiente error:

> Instant Run detected that you are running on a target device that has
>   a work profile or multiple user accounts.
>                     Launching the app under a work profile or another user account on the target device will result in a crash.
>                     Learn more about how to run your app under a work profile.

Claro el link que me aparece es [este](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html?utm_source=android-studio#ir-work-profile). Pero ya lo he leído y no he logrado resolver el problema, quisiera por favor que me ayuden a resolver el problema.

El teléfono que utilizo es el *Samsung Galaxy s7 flat*. Ya tengo habilitadas las "opciones de desarrollador" y la "Depuración USB"

Tampoco puedo utilizar el emulador que proporciona Android Studio porque mi Hardware no lo permite.

Comment: tiene habilitado en tu cel las opciones de desarrollar

Comment: Ya he hecho los pasos de esos links, pero no me funciona, ayuda por favor. No sé qué estará saliendo mal.

Answer (score 0):

Usa esto para configurar tu proyecto Iniciando tu aplicación en un [perfil de Trabajo](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html)

Si ejecuta su aplicación con Instant Run y ​​abre su aplicación usando un [perfil de trabajo](https://developer.android.com/work/overview.html) (u otro perfil secundario), su aplicación se bloqueará porque los archivos DEX instrumentados utilizados por Instant Run solo son accesibles desde el espacio de usuario del perfil principal.

Si desea continuar usando Instant Run, simplemente evite abrir su aplicación con el perfil de Trabajo y asegúrese de que su [configuración de ejecución](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html) no use el `--user user_id` indicador.

Si necesita usar su aplicación con el perfil de Trabajo, te recomendamos que cree una nueva configuración de ejecución que incluya el `--user user_id` indicador, especificando el ID de usuario del perfil de Trabajo. Puede encontrar el ID de usuario ejecutando *adb shell pm list users* desde la línea de comando. Cuando utiliza el indicador --user, Android Studio deshabilita Instant Run solo para esa implementación; La ejecución instantánea funcionará nuevamente cuando cambie a una configuración sin la --user.

**Para deshabilitar la ejecución instantánea:**

1-Abra el cuadro de diálogo Configuración o Preferencias.

2- Navegue a Build, Execution, Deployment> Instant Run.

3- Desmarque la casilla junto a Activar ejecución instantánea.**